# Streamable Container for HEVC (H.265)

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, avconv

`flv` is a container which can be used to stream videos while they are being encoded. `flv` supports `h.264` codec.

However, `flv` doesn't support `hevc` codec. Is there any container for `hevc` which is streamable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MPEG -TS. See [here](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2013/04/26/mpeg-hevc-support-in-gpac/):

> All MPEG-2 TS operations from GPAC (client and MP42TS) are supported on
>     HEVC. MP42TS can be used to generate TS files usable for DASH or for
>     injection in modulation chains; it can also be used to send the TS over an
>     UDP or RTP stream in unicast or multicast mode

Comment: I was not aware of GPAC. Will have to look into it. Let's see if this works. I'll update after trying it out. Thanks :)

Comment: It also works on `ffmpeg` with `libx265`

Comment: @aergistal How? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @shivams Eg: `ffmpeg -re -i <input> -c:v libx265 -c:a ... -f mpegts udp://...` You can also output it in `HLS`: `ffmpeg -re -i <input> -c:v libx265 -c:a ... playlist.m3u8`

Comment: apart from mpegts , what are other formats are supported. I want to stream video to an rtmp URL using h265. So do I have flv as the only option or are there any options that I can use for libx265?

Comment: When I use `-f mpegts` Nginx RTMP didn't accept it and did not generate .m3u8 file I got `nginx 404 Not Found ` message when I use this command `ffmpeg  -re -i <input> -s 634x360   -vb 110k -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -ab 38k  -ar 44100 -f mpegts  rtmp://localhost/hls/live`

Comment: RTMP requires `-f flv`. `m3u8` is a playlist for HLS which does not stream over RTMP but over HTTP(S).

Answer (score 1):

A bit old one but Google still lists it...

You can of course use RTSP "push" similar way as you'd do via FLV/RTMP. A bit less known method but also viable and supports H.265 (aka HEVC).

Comment: Thank you @Pavel. Could you elaborate a little more on how to do it? Or some references for the same?

Comment: Short and self-explanatory example would be: `ffmpeg -i input -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp` - taken from [FFmpeg official Streaming Guide](https://fftrac-bg.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide), tested against Wowza Streaming Engine.